# R studio code running error in mycalc invalid operation

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, division, vector-multiplication

`Error in mycalc(DF[1, 1], DF[1, 2], "multiply") : Invalid operation. Use either 'sum' or 'divide'.` Help.

multiplying and dividing the value of columns

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `*`:

```
DF <- data.frame(c(1,2), c(3,4))
DF[1, 1]*DF[1, 2]
```

Output:

```
[1] 3
```